# MongoDB find many objects from array, using array of matching id's

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filtering, grouping, pymongo

I have an array structures as such

[image]

I've been trying to use an aggregation pipeline, and bulk.find() with a loop, and the $in operator, and none of these options seem to give me the power to (find many by an array of inputted id's).
How do you find many objects in an array filtering by an array of ID's that I already have?
I'm using **PyMongo**

Comment: Are you looking for array returned to be filtered based on the `ids` provided. I see many fields here as array, which one do u want to apply filter on? Please update the question with an example and expected output.

Comment: I would like to collect an array of the objects you see here 0-7, the outermost 'groups' is also a direct key in a collection. I have an array of 'source_id' values I want to use to filter these objects. p.s I'm using an ```{'_id': ObjectId()}``` to find this collection as well.

Comment: Using an aggregation pipeline, use an $in match after unwinding.

Answer (score 0):

Using an aggregation pipeline, use an $in match after unwinding

```
[
   {$unwind: "groups.asana"},
   {"source_id": {$in: ["id1", "id2", "id3"]}}
]
```